# UIWebView Deprecated Warning

Tags: ios, uiwebview, app-store, wkwebview

Have replaced UIWebView with WKWebView also replaced third party frameworks which uses UIWebView. But post archiving the build, I can still find UIWebView matches in MY_APP.xarchive file in below mwntioned path.

1. Binary file ./dSYMs/TARGET_NAME.appex.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/TARGET_NAME matches
2. Binary file ./dSYMs/APP_NAME.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/APP_NAME matches
3. Binary file ./Products/Applications/MyApp.app/MyApp matches

Will this still stop me to submit my app to the AppStore or is that ok to have UIWebView matches in above files?

Answer (score 0):

In `Podfile`,  Remove all pods line and `pod install`

Again add all latest pods and `pod install`.

The problem will be solved. Xcode doesn't update all files when `pod update`

I spent lot of time on this & found this.

Comment: Thanks.. but it didn't work for me. Still I am getting the same output.

Comment: @user14115058 where you able to fix this?